# multiply 2 vectors with different length such that first vector is multiplied with each element of the second vector

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

How can I use `numpy` multiply 2 1-Dim vector with different length such that first vector is multiplied with each element of the second vector

```
A = np.array(
    [1, 2]
)
B = np.array(
    [10, 20, 30]
)

# expected result
np.array(
    [10, 20], # 10 * [1, 2]
    [20, 40], # 20 * [1, 2]
    [30, 60] # 30 * [1, 2]
)
```

Comment: `np.einsum('i,j', B, A)` or `B[:, None]*A`?

Comment: `B[:, None]*A` worked